RPI5, Xubuntu 24.04 WiFi disappeared
I updated my RPi5 to ubuntu24.04 (xubuntu 24.04) and things worked fine.  Except...
The wifi gadgetry is not visible.  iconfig -a does not show the wifi device.
Booting the older 22.04 makes it visible again.
Missing driver?  What do I look for?

Did you upgrade or fresh install 24.04?

Upgrade on top of 22.04.

Please try flashing an image of 24,04 instead of upgrading

Wilco, but not for a couple of weeks.  I found https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/raspberry2.html and I'll see if it helps.

How did you upgrade? Did Ubuntu offer you the upgrade?
